# How to resolve declaration errors

Tags: c++, scope, compilation, declaration, stdstring

I am attempting to run a code that takes a user inputted standard time and convert it to military time. For the user input, the hours can be typed as one or two digits, and AM/PM can be typed in any way. Given that, the code I have is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string time, hour, minute, amPm, miltime;

char amPmCheck;

int main()
{

    cout<<"Enter time:\n";

    cin>>time;

    colon = time.find(':');

    space = time.find (' ');

    hour = time.substr(0, colon);

    minute = time.substr(colon + 1, space);

    amPm = time.substr(space, back);

    amPmCheck = amPm[0];

    timeConversion(hour, minute, amPmCheck);

    return 0;
}


void timeConversion(hour, minute, amPmCheck)
{
    if(amPmCheck == 'a'||'A')
    {
        if(int(hour) == 12)
        {
            hour.assign('00');
        }
        else if (int(hour) <= 9)
        {
            hour.insert(0, '0');
        }
    }
    else
        if(int(hour) < 12)
        {
            hour.assign(12+int(hour));
        }

    miltime = hour + minute

    cout<< "Corresponding military time is", miltime;
}
```

However when attempting to compile the code, I get the following errors from my chosen compiler:

```
main.cpp:50:25: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
             hour.assign('00');
                         ^~~~
main.cpp:15:8: error: 'std::string time' redeclared as different kind of symbol
 string time, hour, minute, amPm miltime;
        ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/pthread.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/gthr.h:148,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/time.h:192:15: note: previous declaration 'time_t time(time_t*)'
 extern time_t time (time_t *__timer) __THROW;
               ^~~~
main.cpp:44:21: error: variable or field 'timeConversion' declared void
 void timeConversion(hour, minute, amPmCheck)
                     ^~~~
main.cpp:44:35: error: 'amPmCheck' was not declared in this scope
 void timeConversion(hour, minute, amPmCheck)
                                   ^~~~~~~~~
```

I am still relatively new to programming, so any information on what my mistakes are and what the simplest way to fix them is would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to put types for the parameters here; `void timeConversion(hour, minute, amPmCheck)` and move the whole function definition before `main()`.

Comment: You should get a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282). It will greatly speed up your learning progress.

Comment: `string time` rename `time` to something else. The name `time` is already taken. For example use `timestr`.

Comment: Please learn the type system of C++.

Comment: The compiler actually tells you exactly what is happening: `'std::string time' redeclared as different kind of symbol` followed by `previous declaration 'time_t time(time_t*)'` . So the identifier `time` was already used for some other purpose. For the future, please read compiler error messages VERY carefully. They used to be quite cryptic, bit the modern compilers got much better at it.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues here, first:

- change

`void timeConversion(hour, minute, amPmCheck)`

to

`void timeConversion(string & hour, string & minute, string & amPmCheck)`

if you want to deal with function parameters

- or change the same function (in your case better option) to:

`void timeConversion()`

since you are dealing with global variables anyway.

- put `timeConversion` function before `main` or use pre-declaration like this:

`void timeConversion();`

also before `main` function.

PS. Please read good book about C++.

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is no need to declare these variables as namespace variables.

```
string time, hour, minute, amPm, miltime;

char amPmCheck;
```

They should be declared as local variables if the function `main`.

And there are no declarations of variables `colon` and `space`.

This statement

```
amPm = time.substr(space, back);
```

does not make sense. The variable `amPm` is declared as having type `char` instead of the type `std::string`.

The function declaration

```
void timeConversion(hour, minute, amPmCheck)
```

is wrong. You did not specify the types of the function parameters.

Statements like this

```
    if(int(hour) == 12)
```

does not make sense. You have to use at least the standard function `std::stoi` to convert an object of type `std::string` to an object of type `int`.

In the statement

```
hour.assign('00');
```

there is used a multibyte char literal. It seems you mean double quotes

```
hour.assign("00");
```

The same is valid for the statement

```
hour.insert(0, '0');
```

This statement

```
hour.assign(12+int(hour));
```

also does not make sense.

There are too many errors in your code.

You should at first read the documentation of the class `std::basic_string` to know how to use its nethods.

And do not use the derictive

```
using namespace std;
```

It can be the reason of the error of conflicted declarations. 
See for example the error message of your compiler

```
main.cpp:15:8: error: 'std::string time' redeclared as different kind of symbol
 string time, hour, minute, amPm miltime;
        ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/pthread.h:24:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/gthr.h:148,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/time.h:192:15: note: previous declaration 'time_t time(time_t*)'
 extern time_t time (time_t *__timer) __THROW;
               ^~~~
```

Use instead qualified names for standard names declared in the namespace `std`.